# Mootools/Javascript scope question

Tags: javascript, mootools, scope

I'm writing a Mootools plugin and having trouble understanding a scoping issue. Some code to convey my context:

```
var pluginName = new Class({
   implements: [ Options ],

  initialize: function(paramOne, options) {
    this.setOptions(options);
  },

  someFunction: function() {
    $$('menu').each(function(menu) {
      // SCOPE OF INTEREST
    });
  }
};
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to access the options object in the scope where I've written 'SCOPE OF INTEREST'. I know one way would be to set a variable at the beginning of someFunction like so:

```
someFunction: function() {
    var optionIWantToAccess = this.options.relevantOption;
    $$('menu').each(function(menu) {
      // now optionIWantToAccess is available here
    });
  }
```

but this seems kind of clumsy and smells of a better alternative. A more general version of this question is: Can I access the class-level scope (not sure if that's the right term....but the scope inside the initialize function is what I'm talking about) inside a Mootools iterator?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the function to the instance.

```
someFunction: function() {
  $$('menu').each(function(menu) {
    // 'this' is still the original instance
    this.options.relevantOption;
  }.bind(this))
}
```

Function#bind is not available in old browsers, but adding support for it is very straight-forward.

Comment: couple of things. mootools prototypes Function and adds `bind` if not available natively. Second, `Array.each` accepts a second parameter after the callback function, i.e. `bind` so you can just do `array.each(fn() { this.something(); }, this);` where `this` is the scope you bind to but it can be anything you need it to be - which is the cleanest/most readable way to do it

Comment: Also, check out the `Binds` mutator, which is a nicer/cleaner way of binding scope.

Comment: Thanks guys!!!! (why is there a minimum comment length that forces me to put 4 exclamation points after a simple thank you?)

Comment: @Oskar Krawczyk to be fair, I am not a big fan of the binds mutator anymore. It adds an overhead to class instantiation code and through including mootools-more (or at least `Class.Binds`). It can also be difficult to read as it's easy to miss the declaration (in a long class) -- just looking at the relevant section of code may not make much sense - unless you remember to look at the class top. Then, there's extended classes which may even be in other files...